# Azure Webapp to azure Marklogic on VM using .net XCC library : An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used [::ffff:10.10.1.4]:9501

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, networking, marklogic, azure-web-app-service

We have a webapp hosted on azure Appservice plan talking to Marklogic server hosted on Azure VM.
With webapp and VM talking over point to site VPN and are on the same VNET

When we call Marklogic server hosted at xcc://admin:admin@10.10.1.4:9501 using .net XCC library.
We are getting an error :

> An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used
>   [::ffff:10.10.1.4]:9501
>
> stacktrace Message:    at
>   Marklogic.Xcc.Impl.SessionImpl.SubmitRequest(Request request)    at
>   IET.TV.Common.MarkLogicHelper.MarkLogicHelper.Invoke(String moduleUri,
>   String inputSearchDetails)    at
>   IET.TV.Common.MarkLogicHelper.MarkLogicHelper.InvokeToSingleString(String
>   moduleUri, String separator, String inputSearchDetails)

Is there is a way to control how the address format is generated using .net XCC library.
Tried disabling IPV6 option on the VM still didnt work is there any other options to get it working

Marklogic library version used is MarkXCC.Net-8.0-6 and MVC 4 running on .net 4.6.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to work on Windows 10

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929852

You need to disable IPV6 at the host level for Windows to not resolve to an IPV6 address.

There is a wizard for disabling IPV6 and re-enabling it, as well as registry instructions.  I tested the wizard and it worked for me. (It was previously giveng the same error as you).

I first tried this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f59xd138(v=vs.90).aspx

and it did not work.  Fine print 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2sb8t9k(v=vs.90).aspx

> This setting enables IPv6 support for the obsolete members of the Dns
>   class: BeginGetHostByName, BeginResolve, EndGetHostByName, EndResolve,
>   GetHostByAddress, GetHostByName, and Resolve. For other members of the
>   System.Net namespace, IPv6 addresses may be returned if IPv6 is
>   enabled in the operating system.

Comment: Since my application are running as webapps in App service plan. I am not sure if we can execute these files. Since it doesnt show any VM.  Also to reflect the ipv6  changes we need to restart the server. There are no options to restart the VM.

Comment: I still tried with a powershell script  and tried running it as webjob.                                            "New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TCPIP6\Parameters -Name DisabledComponents -PropertyType DWord -Value 0xFF"              but it wont allow me to change registry                                :PermissionDenied: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...PIP6\P